# Cumulatively count values in a vector to form a matrix when not all possible values will always show up

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector that could have any values from 1 to 7 in it, but not necessarily all of those values will appear, for example:

```
top <- c(2,1,2,5,5,5)
```

and I want to produce a matrix:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]

[1,]  0    1    0    0    0    0    0

[2,]  1    1    0    0    0    0    0

[3,]  1    2    0    0    0    0    0

[4,]  1    2    0    0    1    0    0

[5,]  1    2    0    0    2    0    0

[6,]  1    2    1    0    3    0    0
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, nor the logic relationship between the initial vector and the final matrix. Please clarify your question, and add any code that you have tried.

Comment: @user3651829 I posted a vectorized solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method with base R that produces the matrix in your example.

```
sapply(1:7, function(x) cumsum(top == x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    2    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    2    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    1    2    0    0    2    0    0
[6,]    1    2    0    0    3    0    0
```

For values 1 through 7, return a logical for if the value matches top values, then use `cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized option using `colCumsums`

```
library(matrixStats)
colCumsums(+(outer(top, 1:7, FUN = "==")))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    2    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    2    0    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    1    2    0    0    2    0    0
#[6,]    1    2    0    0    3    0    0
```